# Why my python class not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

As shown in the code, `Dog` is a subclass of `Pet`. When I create an instance of `Dog`, I can't get the `species` of it. By the way, I am following [this article](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/)?

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self, name, species):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSpecies(self):
        return self.species

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} is a {1}".format(self.name, self.species)


class Dog(Pet):

    def __int__(self, name, chaseCats):
        Pet.__init__(self, name, "dog")
        self.chaseCats = chaseCats

    def getChaseCats(self):
        return self.chaseCats
```

When create an instance:

```
mister_dog = Dog("Huang ~", True)
print mister_dog.getSpecies()
```

It returns: `True` rather than `dog`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo. The subclass `Dog` first method is named `__int__`, rather than `__init__`. Therefore the initializer is not being defined in the subclass and you are only calling the base class's `__init__` directly.

By the way, you could start using the `super()` method as well, rather than the unbound method.